# Explanation of ceiling fan working principle

Tags: capacitor, fan

Can anyone explain how ceiling fan works; why the capacitor; how the fan rotates. Theory and practical.

Single phase induction motor are very easy to understand. In this ceiling fan, the windings are not like induction motor windings. There are two sets of windings. One is clockwise and another is anticlockwise. There rotating part is a magnet ring that is outside of the armature. Can anyone explain how this type of motor works?

Comment: And what have you done to try and answer this yourself. A ceiling fan runs on AC mains so start at finding out how an AC motor works.

Comment: Show us what you did yourself to find out. Where you get stuck. In that case we are willing to help.

Comment: I guess my question is not clear. Single phase induction motor are very easy to understand. If u open the ceiling fan, u will see the winding are not as induction motor winding. There are 2 sets of winding one in clockwise and another is anticlockwise. There is a magnet ring outside of the armature which actually rotates. Ceiling fan running is not that easy to understand especially the practical part i.e what is happening inside the fan when the fan is in running state. I found a lot of theory part in books and in internet but none explained the practical part. Help me...

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate question. See revision.

Comment: It would help a lot to have pictures showing the details of the inside of the motor.

Answer (score 0):

If the motor contains a permanent magnet, it is not an induction motor. It is probably a permanent-magnet synchronous motor (PMSM). A brushless DC (BLDC) motor is essentially the same thing, but requires an electronic commutator or speed controller and operates from a DC supply.

Assuming it is a PMSM, the capacitor provides a phase shift to provide a second phase that is "split" from the single-phase supply. Look up "capacitor run single-phase motor" to find a detailed explanation. The second set of windings would be the auxiliary or second phase winding that is connected in series with the capacitor. Most such motors are induction motors. A motor with a permanent magnet rotor must be a PMSM. This is an unusual motor, but it may be a less expensive alternative for a ceiling fan.

As it is described, the motor can only run at a fixed speed. For variable speed, it would need to be configured as a BLDC motor with an electronic controller. BLDC motors are the preferred motor for computer cooling fans. Computer-fan motors have an electronic commutator built into them.